# Running gRPC server and client in JUnit test (sometimes) leads to a deadlock

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, grpc, grpc-java

Often when I consider a new library or technology, I create a small POC or test program to get a feel for it. So I did with [gRPC-Spring-Boot-Starter](https://yidongnan.github.io/grpc-spring-boot-starter/en/). A simple example code is posted below my question text.

This sample has been extended in complexity and eventually, the library has found its way into production code. So far it has survived many runs under moderate load.
Note that, naturally, the production service is not client to itself. But the production gRPC service is in fact client to *other* gRPC services.

Now I was thinking to write some kind of between-unit-and-integration test where I spin up local instances (starting with a single one) of those other gRPC services (pulling data from some static local resource, for example). Basically, this test code looks very much like the one posted below my question.

However - as soon as we poll for results in `forEachRemaining()`, the test ends up hanging: I suspect a deadlock in `ClientCalls#waitAndDrain` (`io.grpc:grpc-stub`).

The funny thing is - this does not happen if the client were created "manually", i.e. without utilizing the third-party Spring extension:

```java
ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget("localhost:9091")
             .defaultLoadBalancingPolicy("round_robin")
             .usePlaintext()
             .build();
StockStaticDataRequestServiceBlockingStub stub = StockStaticDataRequestServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);
```

I use Spring Boot 2.6.3, gRPC-Spring-Boot-Starter 2.13.1, gRPC 1.44.0, proto 3.19.2 and netty 4.1.73, for what it is worth.

Now I wonder if someone here encountered similar issues or can give me some pointers while I am trying to figure out the inner workings of gRPC more.

Added [sample project on GH](https://github.com/bcamel/stackoverflow_grpc_starter).
The `main` branch contains the - maybe dubious - test setup I chose in the beginning, branches are some refinements, like using @Abhijit Sarkar's `grpc-test` library. Tests are [green](https://github.com/bcamel/stackoverflow_grpc_starter/actions) so far.

```yaml
grpc:
  client:
    stocks:
      address: 'static://localhost:9091'
      enableKeepAlive: false
      negotiationType: plaintext
  server:
    port: 9092
```

```java
@SpringBootTest
class TestGrpc {

    @GrpcClient("stocks")
    private StockStaticDataRequestServiceBlockingStub stub;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void setUp() throws Exception {
        final Server server = ServerBuilder
            .forPort(9091)
            .addService(new StockStaticDataRequestTestService())
            .build();
        server.start();
        final Thread serverThread = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                server.awaitTermination();
            } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        });
        serverThread.setDaemon(false);
        serverThread.start();
    }

    @Test
    void testClient() {
        StockStaticManyDataRequest request = StockStaticManyDataRequest.newBuilder()
            .addAllTickerSymbols(List.of("AAPL"))
            .build();
        stub.getManyStockStatics(request).forEachRemaining(security -> {
            LOG.info("security={}", security);
        });
    }

}
```

```java
public class StockStaticDataRequestTestService extends StockStaticDataRequestServiceImplBase {
    @Override
    public void getManyStockStatics(StockStaticManyDataRequest request, StreamObserver<Security> responseObserver) {
        responseObserver.onNext(Security.newBuilder()
            .setSecurity("TEST-MANY")
            .build());
        responseObserver.onNext(Security.newBuilder()
            .setSecurity("TEST-MORE")
            .build());
        responseObserver.onCompleted();
    }
}
```

```proto
message Security {
  string tickerSymbol = 1;
  string security = 2;
}

message StockStaticManyDataRequest {
  repeated string tickerSymbols = 1;
}

service StockStaticDataRequestService {
  rpc getManyStockStatics(StockStaticManyDataRequest) returns (stream Security) {}
}
```

Comment: What does your proto file look like for this?

Comment: I added the proto to the original question. Note that my POC unit test does not lead to a deadlock, neither with a hand-rolled client nor with @GrpcClient from the spring-grpc-starter lib. Another curiosity. I cannot post the production code proto, but it is similar - just request and response messages are more complicated. In my test of production code, I do not use the actual implementation of the gRPC service I want to spin up in my test, but a stand-in which is, in essence, doing similar things as the test code posted in my question: Return a canned set of responses.

Comment: Try moving the Server  variable to the class scope. Then add @AfterAll
 static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception { server.shutdown();
 }

Comment: Now that you mention it I noticed that POC test uses `@BeforeAll` while my production test uses instance method `@BeforeEach` and `@AfterEach` (to shutdown the channel in case of the hand-rolled solution). Now, I tried shutting down the server in a tearDown, both as static and instance variable. No dice - POC test works as expected, production version hangs.

Comment: If you’re using JUnit 5, you can simplify your code *greatly* by using the library [grpc-test](https://github.com/asarkar/grpc-test). As the README says, it “_Includes a JUnit 5 Extension that can automatically release gRPC resources at the end of the test_”. Disclaimer: I’m the author of that library.

Comment: Any stack trace when this happens?

Comment: Stacktrace: https://pastebin.com/5detVnAj

Comment: @mats, I brought your code down. Your GH code does not dead-lock for me. Is there any way that you can recreate this in a simpler example?  Another observation ... jar version conflicts in your GH code. Please try to use gprc 1.42.2, <grpc.version>1.42.2</grpc.version> as net.devh:grpc-server-spring-boot-starter:2.13.1.RELEASE was built with that version. In your larger production projects, look for jar version conflicts.

Comment: @aerobiotic Yes, the GH version with the "simple" test (actually, I made it more complicated locally to grow closer to the production codebase) does not deadlock and allows for more than 1 test in the same test class to succeed without even having to worry about server shutdown. Not the cleanest, but it is intended for a proof-of-concept. I have not yet figured out what part of the production codebase changes the behaviour. In fact, I do no longer use spring-grpc-client/server-starter in it (from the next release).

Comment: @aerobiotic Jar version conflicts - yes, they can come up indeed. If gRPC used semver (didn't check), going from 1.42.x to 1.44.x may introduce surprises. Usually use the enforcer plugin with upper bounds checker, but it would not alarm here, of course. Also, sometimes have to increase a transitive dependency's version due to vulnerability scans popping up. Do not know whether 1.42.x can be pinned then and whether spring-grpc-...-starter updates its deps fast enough. Maybe one more reason to drop this Spring extension.

Answer (score 1):

I think what the problem might be is that you should not be starting the server at all. There are some grpc-spring-boot-starter annotations that should be added to a test configuration class that will start / stop the server. See details here.

https://yidongnan.github.io/grpc-spring-boot-starter/en/server/testing.html#integration-tests

I also tried to make what you have work, but the server once started really won't shutdown. This makes the next test suite that runs fail due to port conflicts when it tries to start.

Here's my test class.

```
@Slf4j
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringJUnitConfig(classes = { ServiceIntegrationTestConfiguration.class })
@DirtiesContext
class TestGprc {
    @GrpcClient("stocks")
    private StockStaticDataRequestServiceBlockingStub stub;
    
    /**
     * @throws java.lang.Exception
     */
    @BeforeAll
    static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
        log.info("setUpBeforeClass");
    }

    /**
     * @throws java.lang.Exception
     */
    @AfterAll
    static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
        log.info("tearDownAfterClass");
    }

    /**
     * @throws java.lang.Exception
     */
    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() throws Exception {
    }

    /**
     * @throws java.lang.Exception
     */
    @AfterEach
    void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    @DirtiesContext
    void testClient() {
        StockStaticManyDataRequest request = StockStaticManyDataRequest.newBuilder()
            .addAllTickerSymbols(List.of("AAPL"))
            .build();
        stub.getManyStockStatics(request).forEachRemaining(security -> {
            log.info("security={}", security);
        });
    }
}
```

Here's the configuration project.

```
@Configuration
@ImportAutoConfiguration({ GrpcServerAutoConfiguration.class, // Create required server beans
        GrpcServerFactoryAutoConfiguration.class, // Select server implementation
        GrpcClientAutoConfiguration.class,
        GrpcStarterApplication.class})
public class ServiceIntegrationTestConfiguration {
    // add mock beans here of needed. 
}
```

My overrides for the properties. see application-test.yaml

```
grpc:
  client:
    stocks:
      address: in-process:test
      enableKeepAlive:
      negotiationType:
  server:
    inProcessName: test
    port: -1
```

I posted the entire maven project here:
https://github.com/aerobiotic/grpc-spring-starter

Simply clone it and mvn clean install :-)

As far as your dead-lock goes in your production code:

1. make sure you are calling onCompleted
2. check your catch blocks and make sure onError is being called and that there is logging happening.
3. It's possible that starting the server and not getting it shutdown is affecting something. Perhaps test code is connecting to a server from a previous test.

Comment: Thank you for the extensive answer! To clarify: Production code does not deadlock, "only" the so-called integration test does, and only in case of using `@GrpcClient` for the client. The link about testing gRPC-starter code is very interesting. However, there is slight difference in my case: I have a gRPC service which itself consumes a gRPC API, thus has a gRPC client embedded. My test thus needs to provide *two* gRPC services - the dependency and the actual one. Isolated, this does not seem to be an issue. With the production codebase, it is. I will add a GH link to the (working) example.